# Payment section on Order detail Page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, sales-order, payment

On the admin side, payment section (Order detail page) data is not showing. I am trying to override the default code or change the current code but couldn't find the proper class. Need guidelines for the issue.Thanks
[image]

Comment: can you please let me know where exactly are you getting this section. As I am unable to find.

Comment: @poojansharma I am getting this on clicking this link. https://www.screencast.com/t/h72sleNcBQi